# Best way to exclude arbitrary rows/data points from google sheets chart

Tags: google-sheets

I've got a chart I'm creating in google sheets to calculate sales trends in a restaurant. Basically, I dump in all the daily sales data from the POS, run some query functions to pull out and aggregate the data I want, then make a chart from that. I'd like to be able to arbitrarily exclude certain rows for the chart though, for example week 17 when we closed early due to a power outage.
[image: Example Data]

My first attempt was to use multiple ranges in the chart and combine them vertically. This worked at removing the row I didn't want, but with a side-effect.
[image: Chart]

As you can see, none of the normal options for choosing which series to display etc. are there. They are when I'm using one single range, but as soon as I set the data range to two vertically combined ranges they disappear, with the first column of the range being used as the x-axis and every other column being used as a series.

Is this the intended behavior? If so, why? And what is the best way for me to arbitrarily exclude rows from my chart? It's not as simple as just deleting them, as they're auto generated by query functions.

Answer (score 1):

If you hide a row in the table used as the data source for a chart (either by using hide/group rows from the right-click context menu, or by applying a filter to the table using the toolbar), this results in the data for those rows being removed from the chart. You'll also see an additional 'include hidden/filtered data' option appear in the chart options when you do this which allows this default behaviour to be overridden.